# HowTo Add an Alias to a Search Managed Property using Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, search, managed-property

How can I add an Alias to a SharePoint Search Managed Property using PowerShell?

I can see it using the GUI, but I cannot find anywhere where I can add an alias to a SharePoint Search Managed Property using PowerShell.

Am I missing something?

Comment: check this link http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2012/07/sp2013-search-quickie-createmap-a-new-managed-property-powershell/ addalias

Comment: Hi Waqas
In the example you quoted I could not find an example of adding an alias using powershell.
Perhaps you could show me where it is ?

Comment: Hi Waqas

I have got it now - I understand what the post is saying.

I need $managedProperty.AddAlias("AliasName");Thanks




Nigel

Comment: I add that as answer, if you marked it.

Answer (score 1):

There is one property called alias (which you can use .`addAlias()`).

```
$managedproperty.addAlias("alias");
```

[Source](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2012/07/sp2013-search-quickie-createmap-a-new-managed-property-powershell/)